# How do I make my level scroll side-to-side as the player moves?

Tags: camera, python, pygame, side-scroller

I am trying to figure out how can I make a side-scrolling view in Pygame.

If I am moving right or left, I want the portion of the level shown on-screen to shift to follow the player character.

[Here is an animation of my game:](https://gyazo.com/636fef8a16198b24bc0496f566c57d9c)

[image: Platformer animation]

```
import pygame
pygame.init()


window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("GET LOAD OF THIES")


# Character class
class players(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.fall = 0
        self.speed = 5

# enemy class 1
class enemys(object):
    def __init__(self,cordx,cordy,cordheight,cordwidth):
        self.cordx = cordx
        self.cordy = cordy
        self.cordheight = cordheight
        self.cordwidth = cordwidth

# enemy class 2
class enemyss(object):
    def __init__(self,xs,ys,sheights,swidths):
        self.xs = xs
        self.ys = ys
        self.sheights = sheights
        self.swidths = swidths

class lava(object):
    def __init__(self,lavax,lavay,lavawidth,lavaheight):

        self.lavax = lavax
        self.lavay = lavay
        self.lavawidth = lavawidth
        self.lavaheight = lavaheight



# enemy class 3
class enemysss(object):
    def __init__(self,velx,vely,velheight,velwidth):
        self.velx = velx
        self.vely = vely
        self.velwidth = velwidth
        self.velheight = velheight


# Colors
NiceBlue = (0,214, 82)
NiceGreen = (214,0,82)

# FPS
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Defininition for the class player/enemys
playerman = players(50,390,20,20)
enemy1 = enemys(150,390,100,10)
enemy2 = enemyss(320,320,100,10)
enemy3 = enemysss(120,250,100,10)
enemy4 = lava(0,459,500,40)


# Main loop
runninggame = True
while runninggame:
    # Frames per second
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # Exit Event
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runninggame = False
        #Draw The enemys and Main Characte
    window.fill((0,0,0))
    player = pygame.draw.rect(window, (NiceGreen), (playerman.x,playerman.y,playerman.height,playerman.width))
    enemy = pygame.draw.rect(window, (NiceBlue), (enemy1.cordx,enemy1.cordy,enemy1.cordheight,enemy1.cordwidth))
    soenemy = pygame.draw.rect(window, (NiceBlue), (enemy2.xs,enemy2.ys,enemy2.sheights,enemy2.swidths))
    dudeenemy = pygame.draw.rect(window, (NiceBlue), (enemy3.velx,enemy3.vely,enemy3.velheight,enemy3.velwidth))
    thisanotherenemy = pygame.draw.rect(window, (230,4,231), (enemy4.lavax,enemy4.lavay,enemy4.lavawidth,enemy4.lavaheight))


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerman.x -= playerman.speed
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerman.x += playerman.speed
    if not playerman.isJump:

        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
# ----------------------------------------------------- # enem1 collisio
# both of my 2 enemy squares collisions push me back when ever I Jump on the top of them on there sides but when I jump on the middle of of both of them it seems to work if I just want it so when I jump on both of my squares I just don't get pushed back 
        player.topleft = (playerman.x, playerman.y)
        collide = False
        if player.colliderect(enemy):
            collide = True
            playerman.y = enemy.top - player.height
            if player.right > enemy.left and  player.left < enemy.left - player.width:
                playerman.x = enemy.left - player.width
            if player.left < enemy.right and  player.right > enemy.right + player.width:
                playerman.x = enemy.right

        if player.colliderect(soenemy):
            collide = True
            playerman.y = soenemy.top - player.height
            if playerman.y > soenemy.left and player.left < enemy.left - player.width:
                playerman.x = soenemy.left  - player.width
            if player.left < soenemy.left and player.right > soenemy.right + player.width:
                playerman.x = soenemy.right
        if player.colliderect(dudeenemy):
            collide = True
            playerman.y = dudeenemy.top - player.height
            if playerman.y > dudeenemy.left and player.left < dudeenemy.left - player.width:
                playerman.x = dudeenemy.left  - player.width
            if player.left < dudeenemy.left and player.right > dudeenemy.right + player.width:
                playerman.x = dudeenemy.right
        if player.colliderect(thisanotherenemy):
            collide = True
            playerman.y = thisanotherenemy.top - player.height
            if playerman.y > thisanotherenemy.left and player.left < thisanotherenemy.left - player.width:
                playerman.x = thisanotherenemy.left  - player.width
            if player.left < thisanotherenemy.left and player.right > thisanotherenemy.right + player.width:
                playerman.x = thisanotherenemy.right





        if player.bottom >= 500:
            collide = True
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10
            playerman.y = 500 - player.height

        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
            playerman.fall = 0
    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount > 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount * abs(playerman.JumpCount)) * 0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.JumpCount = 10
            playerman.isJump = False



        # update winodw event
    pygame.display.update()
# quit event
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll basically want to define a `Camera` class. In this case you could make it as simple as being only a screen offset, but a zoom factor might be nice too. This camera could then have a function that converts *world coordinates* into *screen coordinates*, which you would call when drawing objects.
The position of this camera could then be changed based on the position of the target it is tracking.

As a side note: You may want to use [`Rect`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect) for your collision detection, that would be provided by your player and enemy classes. `Rect`s have convenient functions like [`clip`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.clip), [`colliderect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) and [`collidelist`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist) that could make your code a lot simpler.